# How to configure a User Signup Workflow in API 3.0.0 and BPS?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-business-process

I configured a User Signup Workflow in API 3.0.0 and BPS (EI 6.5.0) by article https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Learn/ConsumeAPI/Customizations/adding-a-user-signup-workflow/.

When a user registered on API Devportal, he receives message "User registration completed successfully".

But he must not receive these message, he must receive a message "Waiting for approval".

Admin receives Approval Task to approve creation of a user in API Admin Portal.

What is wrong? Did anybody test workflows in API 3.0?

I tested the configuration in API 2.6.0. Everything is fine.

Comment: Can the user login in before the admin approves?

Comment: @Bee yes, user can login before admin approves.

Comment: API Subscription Workflow and Application Creation Workflow work good, problem with User Signup Workflow